# How to get all names starting with J without using LIKE keyword in sql?

Tags: sql

How to get all names starting with 'J' or any 'letter' without using LIKE keyword in sql?

Comment: Using which DBMS?  You have three of them tagged...

Comment: First of all you need to decide which DBMS you are using. Second, this is a rather bizarre requirement. Is this a homework assignment? You could use LEFT(SomeColumn, 1) or SUBSTRING(SomeColumn, 0,  1)

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please explain why you don't want to use `LIKE`.  That is a fine approach in SQL and portable across databases.

Comment: Ha man @Gordon Linoff as the question sounds weird, many people are weird and one of them asked this question in my technical interview. And I used to use LIKE to do such queries But I started wondering how after he asked that question.

Comment: I am using MS sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Solution**

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTR( name, 1, 1 ) = 'J'
```

**MySQL & PosgreSQL Solution**

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEFT( name, 1 ) = 'J'
```

**SQL Server Solution**

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTRING( name, 1, 1 ) = 'J'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM FooTable
 WHERE LEFT(FooField, 1) = 'J'
```